# How to reduce size of embedded images in Illustrator file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-size, raster, optimization

I have an artwork file in Illustrator which has a lot of images embedded into it, I want to reduce the file size before sending to the printer.  I have rasterized the images to 300dpi but that doesn't reduce them much.  I have also tried image trace and then expand but that doesn't really help either.  Does anybody have any other solutions, or maybe I am missing some key steps in the above methods that will make it work?

Comment: If you are sending things to print, expect large image sizes.  That's the nature of the game.  Smaller file size usually means lesser quality.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting as a PDF? If so make sure you distill an EPS file, this will make a smaller PDF than a typical 'save as PDF' from Illustrator file. John was right with his answer, if you reduce the image size you will reduce the quality. Make sure the images are only the size they need to be in Photoshop i.e. if your image is 10cm in Illustrator, make sure it is only 10cm wide @300dpi in Photoshop. All images will need to be edited/resized in Photoshop, and relinked in. You cannot re-size in Illustrator. Or consider Indesign for your next job, Indesign can handle larger files sizes much easier.